# Bash awk: parsing variable string into another variable?

Tags: bash, parsing, awk

I would like to extract all the values contained in  $line and put them in variables var1, var2,... varn. I did use this previously to extract the vars from file (in.txt)

```
var1=$(awk  '{print  $1}' < in.txt)
var2=$(awk  '{print  $2}' < in.txt)
....
varn=$(awk  '{print  $n}' < in.txt)
```

How should I change my awk call so as to use $line instead of in.txt?
I tried these for example

```
echo $line | var2=$(awk '{print  $2}')
```

or

```
var2=$(echo $line | awk '{print  $2}')
```

but without success...

========== DETAIL==============

----- calling file:

```
 .....
    name=Matrix
    line=$(sed  -n '/^\[T\]/ {n;p}' in.txt)
    echo 'line: ' $line
    L1=$(./procline_matrix_vars.sh $line 30 $name)
    echo 'L1: ' $L1
```

------- rocline_matrix_vars.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

line=$1
choice=$2

var1=$(echo $line | awk '{print $1}')
var2=$(echo $line | awk '{print $2}')
var3=$(echo $line | awk '{print $3}')
var4=$(echo $line | awk '{print $4}')


if [ $choice == 30 ]; then
    L1=$(printf '\n\n\n%s = [ %s %s %s %s \n' "$3" "$var1" "$var2" "$var3" "$var4") 
fi

echo  "${L1%.}"
```

Comment: `var2=$(echo $line | awk '{print  $2}')` should work, is it not giving you any values when you do `echo "var2"`?

Comment: It works only for the 1st value in in string.

Comment: see also https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001

Comment: @Sundeep I am clearly stating "awk".

Comment: It seems that the different echo's commands are mixturing everything

Comment: not sure why you need `awk`.. also, variable quoting may be an issue.. could you change `$line` to `"$line"` in calling file and just to make it robust, double quote other places and other variables too... you can also use https://www.shellcheck.net/ to catch such issues

Answer (score 1):

a possible way:

```
line="aaa bbb ccc"

var=( $line )

echo "${var[1]}"
echo "my array has ${#var[@]} elements"
```

output

```
bbb
my array has 3 elements
```

maybe shortcut

```
var=( $( awk '{print $1, $2, $10}' file ) )
```